# jQuery - Automating a div switcher

Tags: jquery

on the site I'm currently developing I have a panel on the news page which lists 'Top Stories', and a navigation for switching between stories.

But how would I go about automating it so that it cycles through each story automatically?

Please click the following link for an example - http://jsfiddle.net/cyxLw/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the setInterval function to run the following function to switch to the next story, after checking one exists.

```
if($('div#top-stories').length) {
        setInterval(function() {
            nextStory();
        }, 10000 );
    }
function nextStory() {
    //Check if there is another story, if not show the first story
    if($('div#top-stories ul li.active').next('li').length) {
        var next = $('div#top-stories ul li.active').next('li').attr('id');
    } else {
        var next = $('div#top-stories ul li').first().attr('id');
    }

    $('div#top-stories ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('li#'+next).addClass('active');

    $('div#top-stories div.panel.active').fadeOut(100, function() {
        $('div#'+next+'-box').fadeIn(100).addClass('active');
    }).removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers :

```
$(document).everyTime(1000, function(i) {
  swapStory();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jCarousel plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use setInterval ( "doSomething()", interval_time );

Answer (score 0):

If there's a link in your navigation that moves to the next story in the list then you could use setInterval() to generate a click event on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function autoNext ()
{
    $('#id_of_my_next_story_link').click ();
}

var nextTimer = setInterval (autoNext, 10000); // 10 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setInterval](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/setinterval) it will execute the function repeatedly  after specified time...

i'm assuming that you are dynamically adding the *top stories*

```
var timeAfterYouInsertNewTopStories = 3000;
setInterval(function() {
            //all your code here
        }, timeAfterYouInsertNewTopStories );
```

Comment: I wrote a function to switch to the next story (http://pastie.org/1593506) and used setInterval to run it every 10 seconds. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code. Look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyxLw/7/